# Text Strings must be rendered within a <Text> component error Adobe XD generated React native code

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please what is wrong with this code. I keep getting this error. Code was generated from Adobe XD.

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

const Register = () =>{
  return (
    <View style = {
      {
        "alignItems": "flex-start"
      }
    } >
    <Image style = {
      {
        "marginStart": 22,
        "width": 340,
        "height": 281
      }
    }
    source = {
      require('../assets/images/store.png')
    }
    />
    <View style = {
      {
        "alignItems": "flex-start",
        "paddingStart": 32,
        "paddingTop": 138,
        "marginTop": 2,
        "width": 375,
        "height": 406,
        "borderTopStartRadius": 21,
        "borderTopEndRadius": 28,
        "borderBottomEndRadius": 0,
        "borderBottomStartRadius": 0,
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(6, 87, 118, 255)"
      }
    } >
    <View style = {
      {
        "alignItems": "flex-start"
      }
    } >
    <Text style = {
      {
        "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)",
        "marginStart": 9
      }
    } > Kindly enter your phone number to
    continue </Text>
      <View style = {
        {
          "flexDirection": "row",
          "alignItems": "flex-start",
          "marginTop": 23
        }
      } >
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(128, 9, 124, 255)",
          "marginTop": 154,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > +244 </Text>
      <View style = {
        {
          "alignItems": "flex-start",
          "paddingTop": 5,
          "marginStart": -50,
          "width": 306,
          "height": 175,
          "borderRadius": 8,
          "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"
        }
      } >
      
      <View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }
      } > <Text style = {       
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(252, 7, 7, 255)",
          "marginStart": 2,
          "marginTop": 4,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > +1 </Text>
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(83, 83, 80, 255)",
          "marginStart": 97,
          "marginTop": 3,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > 7066459456 </Text>
      </View>
      <View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }
      } > <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(0, 17, 128, 255)",
          "marginStart": 2,
          "marginTop": 6,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > +44 </Text>
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(83, 83, 80, 255)",
          "marginStart": 85,
          "marginTop": 5,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > 7066459456 </Text>
      </View>
      <View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }
      } > <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(3, 89, 99, 255)",
          "marginStart": 1,
          "marginTop": 6,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > +61 </Text>
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(83, 83, 80, 255)",
          "marginStart": 85,
          "marginTop": 5,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > 7066459456 </Text>
      </View>
      <View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }
      } > <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(103, 126, 6, 255)",
          "marginTop": 8,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > +233 </Text>
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(83, 83, 80, 255)",
          "marginStart": 72,
          "marginTop": 7,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > 7066459456 </Text>
      </View>
      <Text style = {
        {
          "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontSize": 22,
          "color": "rgba(83, 83, 80, 255)",
          "marginStart": 122,
          "marginTop": 7,
          "opacity": 0.72
        }
      } > 7066459456 </Text>
      </View>
      </View>
      </View>
      <View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }
      } > <View style = {
        {
          "alignItems": "flex-start",
          "marginTop": -182,
          "width": 62,
          "height": 51,
          "borderRadius": 7,
          "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"
        }
      }
    />
    <View style = {
      {
        "alignItems": "flex-start",
        "marginStart": 20,
        "marginTop": -182,
        "width": 224,
        "height": 51,
        "borderRadius": 7,
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"
      }
    }
    />
    </View>
    <View style = {
      {
        "alignItems": "flex-start",
        "paddingStart": 20,
        "paddingTop": 17,
        "marginStart": 213,
        "marginTop": 107,
        "width": 102,
        "height": 56,
        "borderRadius": 28,
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"
      }
    } >
    <Text style = {
      {
        "fontFamily": "Montserrat",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "fontSize": 26,
        "color": "rgba(6, 87, 118, 255)"
      }
    } > next </Text>
    </View>
    </View>
    </View>

  );
};
export default Register;
```

Comment: The text: `aaaaa` isn't inside a `Text` component, that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: I have removed that. Still getting the error.

Comment: can you show the line of error ?